# Using live feeds from ArcGIS Online for analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, arcgis-online, map-service, feature-service

I would like to import into arcGIS Desktop a livefeed layer and use it to perform some analysis.

This is the link to web page: http://tmservices1.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/LiveFeeds/Shakemap/MapServer

If I download the layer into ArcGIS for Desktop, this is not editable.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: I don't believe this is something you can do with this.

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you provide in your question is to a map service that will only return an image for display.

To perform analysis you will need to use a feature service instead.

As an introduction to doing this there is an Esri blog entitled [Quick Tips: Consuming Feature Services with Geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/10/quick-tips-consuming-feature-services-with-geoprocessing/):

> Do you work with Feature Services? Do you want to use geoprocessing
>   tools or Python to perform analysis with ArcGIS for Desktop? Here’s a
>   few quick tips for using a hosted feature service from arcgis.com or
>   your own ArcGIS for Server feature service with geoprocessing tools.

Answer (score 0):

That URL is sourced from the [USGS RSS feed.](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/shakerss.xml).

If your organisation has geoevent extension for ArcGIS for Server, there is an out of the box [connector that can consume a RSS](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/share/geoevent-processor/process-event-data/input-connectors.htm) and push the data to a feature service.

This may well be overkill, but you mention performing analysis on a live layer, and this analysis could be incorporated into a geoevent service so that it is done on the fly and therefore your results could be continuously be live as the incoming feed changes.

If you just want a one off copy of the data, you can still download the latest readings from the [USGS in a variety of formats](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/research/shakemap/formats.php) that ArcGIS supports (shp, kml, xyz).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have ArcGIS for server but it is good to know that this functionality exists, thanks.